# How to mount a Microsoft Storage Space HDD to fresh Ubuntu installation

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

I have just upgraded my PC from Windows to Ubuntu, but am having some trouble accessing my HDD. The output of `sudo fdisk -l` is this:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000DM010-2EP1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B5981591-89D5-11E7-81D5-1C1B0D9AFB0C

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1      34     262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc2  264192 1953523711 1953259520 931.4G Microsoft Storage Spaces
```

I have added the following to my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/dev/sdc2 /hdd ntfs defaults,noatime 0 2
```

and then when I run `sudo mount /hdd`, I get the following error:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around
```

I do have a backup of the disk, but would prefer not to have to resort to that. Any idea how I can successfully mount this drive and access it?

Comment: This could be because Win hasn't closed the drive properly due to its fastboot/faststart option (or whatever it is called). If you can boot win, just turn that option off. Good luck!

Comment: @BerntRibbum I no longer have windows on my system unfortunatley. Can I do this from the BIOS?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm afraid you'll have to resort to your backup.

Comment: You may be able to use your Windows repair flash drive. Or download a copy of Windows and use it to turn off hibernation. You can in Linux mount read only, to copy data, also. https://superuser.com/questions/1231582/hdd-with-windows-boot-locked-because-of-hibernation-flag